# Как занести выбранный элемент combobox в массив?

Tags: delphi, pascal

```
for i:=0 to n-1 do 
begin
 a[n-1]:=combobox7.items[combobox7.itemindex]
end
```

**Это не работает**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Это" работает** при n в пределах длины массива, если массив строковый, только цикл ни к чему.

Если массив динамический, и выбранный элемент надо добавить, то

```
SetLength(a, Length(a) + 1); // невыгодно, если таких операций будет много
a[High[a]] := combobox7.items[combobox7.itemindex];
```

В свежих дельфях

```
a := a +  [combobox7.items[combobox7.itemindex]];
```